# load() on click not populating <section>

Tags: jquery, html

I'm trying to load an html file using jquery load() into a `<section>` that is hidden to the right of the viewable screen. The function gets the correct part of the file I'm requesting (as seen in firebug), fires the callback animation (as seen on the screen), but does not populate the `<section>`.

When I console.log() the matched element it looks as if it should be populating the correct section. Help?

My jquery looks like this:

```
$("a.more").not('.contact').click(function (event){
  event.preventDefault();
  var target = $(this).attr('href')+' #content';
  $(this).parents('article').children('section.toPopulate').load(target, function() {
    $(this).parents('article').children('header').animate({
      'left' : -$(this).parent('article').children('header').outerWidth()
    });
    $(this).animate({
      'left' : 0
    });
  });
});
```

The html looks like this (and there are more of these down the page)

```
<article id="projectID" class="project">
  <header class="dark">
    <div class="intro">
      <figure class="logo">
        <img ..>
      </figure>
      <h1>...</h1>
      <div class="text">
        <p>...</p>
      </div>
      <a class="more" href="#">more</a>
    </div>
  </header>
  <section class="slide toPopulate">

  </section>
</article>
```

Thanks!

Comment: `target` is it from the same server?

Comment: definitely strange symptoms since success fires and can see htm in console....try changing to $.get, have more flexibility with repsonse

Comment: I copied / pasted your code into a test page of mine, and it works great. I didn't have all the CSS details, obviously, was using jQuery 1.7.1, and had the HTML5 Doctype declaration at the top, and was testing in Chrome. I might be tempted to try the `.get()` too though, like @charlietfl suggested..!

Comment: The target is on the same server. I'll try `.get()` - I'm wondering if it has to do with the '#content` that is being loaded being an id on the `<body` tag. I'm using 1.7.1 and have html5 declaration. I'm stumped :(

Answer (score 0):

Problem solved. Turns out you can't load() using an id on the `<body>` tag of the external file. Even though it retrieves the file, it won't place it in the DOM. I moved the `id="content"` to a `<div>` inside the `<body>` tag it populated the `<section>`.